# Can bees find alternate sources of water which mosquitoes can't use?

Tags: ecology, mosquitoes, bees

I live in an area where mosquitoes are a disease vector of concern, and I was dutifully sweeping out a puddle when I noticed a lot of bees had gathered there to collect water.

Is this effort to eliminate mosquitoes also harmful to bees?  Is there water I should leave alone for the benefit of bees without risk of increasing the mosquito population?

Comment: Did you do a search using the phrase, "Do bees need water?" This is a site for students, motivated people interested in Biology, and professionals. Oddly for a Q&A site, we require evidence of a search for information in an attempt to answer your own question (a link to a site and a quote is fine.) And fyi, it takes mosquito eggs 6-7 days to emerge from standing water (e.g. puddles) as adults under ideal circumstances. Fresh water in a clean vessel changed daily will not allow mosquitoes to hatch.

Comment: Yes, I did.  That didn't tell me much more than I already knew given I had already seen bees collecting it.  Only why they wanted it, and not much on what they need to be able to collect it safely or how that contrasts with mosquito habits and public health information about what we need to get rid of.

Comment: If there are running water sources around, the bees are fine. Kinda weird so many bees gathered though so maybe there weren't other sources.